# Sequence of 3x3 grids of dots

Tags: visual, sequence

[image]

Has anyone got any ideas on how to go about solving [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/ravensmatrices/comments/198dcbd/anyone_have_any_clue_how_to_solve/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=ios_app&utm_name=ioscss&utm_content=1&utm_term=1)?

Answer (score 1):

The input patterns again in text form (`O=empty, X=filled`):

```
 X O O   O O O   O O O   O X O
 X X O   O O X   O X O   O O X
 X O O   O X X   X X X   X O O
```

Here is a suggestion which is based on simple rules,
although, to be honest, I don't think that this is the intended solution.

The number of filled circles in each 3x3 grid ...

> is 4 3 4 3 
>  if we continue this alternating pattern, the next should be 4

The circles ...

> in the right column/middle row are: `O X O X`  
>  if we continue the alternatig pattern, the next should be `O`

The only pattern from the given choices which fits both principles is:

> the bottom center pattern:  
>  `O X X` 
>  `O O O` 
>  `X X O`

Comment: Similar to my answer, this is only a partial solution...  is the original puzzle even valid and is there actually a solution?

Comment: +1 for trying although I don’t quite follow your logic 

Comment: @Redditposter well, the logic is simple: find the easiest rule(s) to continue these patterns. And yes, if you have enough instances of "if ... then ..." you could justify any pattern, but the aim is to have the simplest explanation. So, in summary, I don't want to say that this is the "nicest" solution. I hope there are more logic ones ;-).

Answer (score 0):

What about

> The bottom right cell?

I suggest it because...

> if you look at each row of the original sequence, the top row has this many dots: 1-0-0-1.  The middle row has 2-1-1-1.   The bottom row has 1-2-3-1.

I think it's right because

> The sequence including the bottom right cell continues a pattern in each row.  Top: 1-0-0-1-0.  Middle: 2-1-1-1-2.  Bottom: 1-2-3-1-2.

Comment: Maybe the anonymous downvoter could propose their own solution or refute mine instead of just downvoting?

Comment: It's just that you've picked an arbitrary set of sequences to follow (the apparent periods of them vary), and there's also no apparent reason for where to place the dots you demand within those rows. It's a very fundamentally arbitrary-seeming pattern if we're to take your answer as correct.

Comment: The period does vary, true, but in absence of a better answer...

Comment: +1 for trying although I don’t quite follow your logic 